# Cannot create dynamically img via javascript

Tags: javascript

I try to create img element via javascript and set it into td element, but id doesn't work. I can't see any image or icon that img is not found. My server is running on localhost now so that's the reason for img url

```
function fillTable(actualMarkers){
        // Get array of classes without jQuery
        var theTable = document.createElement('table');
        theTable.id = 'actualPlaces';
        // Note, don't forget the var keyword!
        for (var i = 0, tr, tdName, tdId, tdImage, imgPlace ; i < actualMarkers.length; i++) {
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            tdId = document.createElement('td');
            tdImage = document.createElement('td');
            tdName = document.createElement('td');
            imgPlace = document.createElement('img');
            imgPlace.src = 'http://localhost:8080/webapp/images/var/webapp/photos/small/tuc.png';
            imgPlace.height = '20';
            imgPlace.width = '20';
            var marker = actualMarkers[i];
            tdId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(marker.get("id")));
            tdId.className = 'unvisible';
            tdImage.appendChild(imgPlace);
            tdName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(marker.get("name")));
            tr.appendChild(tdId);
            tr.appendChild(tdImage);
            tr.appendChild(tdName);
            theTable.appendChild(tr);
        }

        document.getElementById('foundPlaces').appendChild(theTable);
        addRowHandlers();
    }
```

Comment: Is anything written to your browser's Console? (press F12 to open it).

Comment: Is that really the correct path? "/webapp/images/var/webapp/photos" is pretty suspicious. Does the URL work if you copy-paste it directly to the browser's address bar?

Comment: Yes it is right way, because I have Spring servlet on this project and when I copy this URL http://localhost:8080/webapp/images/var/webapp/photos/small/tuc.png to browser image is dowloaded (but not shown)

Comment: Nothing is written in console

Answer (score 0):

Usually the src attribute look like :

```
 imgPlace.src = 'photos/small/tuc.png';
```

Try to change your images path, but I think it's very strange have two time "webapp" in your src url.

Comment: I have Spring servlet on this project. This servlet run on 
localhost:8080/webapp/images/
and this is only the path for image
var/webapp/photos/small/tuc.png
when i access to this url, download for image will started